# javascript/jquery plugin to add support to media queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, media

found out about [this jquery plugin](http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/mediaqueries/) that adds support to media queries

So you can use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wider.css" media="only screen and (min-width: 1200px)" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="handheld-iphone.css" media="only screen and (max-width: 480px), handheld" />
```

and so on, but it does not support this kind of media queries (in stylesheet)

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    body{background:red}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 740px) {

    body{background:yellow}
}
```

Is there any that does?

Comment: How would you expect the plugin to support those in-stylesheet rules? I mean, what should happend with those media queries?

Comment: basically make them work in browsers like IE6/7/8 wich don't take @media queries

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this as well

http://jsfiddle.net/47DSD/

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

     function wResize() {

             var winW = $(window).width();
             var Body = $('body');

         if ( winW < '1024') {
             Body.css({ 'background-color':'red' }); 
         }
         if ( winW < '740' ) {
             Body.css({ 'background-color':'yellow' }); 
         }         

     }

     wResize();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        wResize();
    });

 });
```

---

**Edit:**

You didnt seem to warm up to this, so how about a little more extensive example?

http://jsfiddle.net/47DSD/1/

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet Added a little more extensive jsfiddle into my answer.

Comment: yes.. the problem of that is that i need to SET the CSS styles vía javascript.. and i would like to be able to use the stylesheet ( only )

Comment: @ToniMichaelCaubet You lost me.

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet I just got wondering if you checked out my second jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/47DSD/1/) at all? The important things set up in the js are 3 width values for different window widths and 2 classes that are added or removed when conditions are met. These are all quite static values in my opinion. Anything else goes to the css file.

Comment: Sorry seems the comment i wrote in my iphone last night was not posted :s; The solution you posted is actually valid but not what i'm looking for;
Basically i want a solution compatible with media queries (and not to substitute the media queries). For example: detecting when no media queries are supported and maybe then implement the way you suggest. thanks and sorry for the delay!

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet I can only see one reason for that. Which is if `js` is not enabled. Only thing is that it sort of doesnt matter if you got the media queries and js working together.. as long as the width values match so you dont actually get 4 different changes instead of 2. Though personally I wouldnt worry about `js` not being enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [enquire.js](https://github.com/WickyNilliams/enquire.js).

Answer (score 0):

Wouter van der Graaf made a javascript plugin for media query support in browsers that don't natively support it:

http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/

Comment: Note: Doesn't work on @import'ed stylesheets (which you shouldn't use anyway for performance reasons). Also won't listen to the media attribute of the <link> and <style> elements.